Redis Sentinel - Delete Keys : Command 'UNLINK' is not a registered Redis command
I am trying to delete keys from redis sentinel.
I keep seeing this error :
Command 'UNLINK' is not a registered Redis command.

what's you redis version

UNLINK was introduced with Redis 4.0. I can think of two ways you would get this error:

You are using a version of Redis from before 4.0. This means you are on a very old version of Redis and you should consider upgrading.
You are using a non-standard version of Redis such as a version ported to Windows or perhaps "Redis-compatible" software that some vendors provide.

If you can't change the Redis version you are using, you can use the DEL command instead which was part of Redis 1.0.
Hope this helps and best of luck!
